# Why is not event fired more then once?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, events

I'm creating a follow/unfollw buttons for different members in a system. I'm having an issue with jQuery event not being fired after html is rendered again in the same div where the buttons are. The follow/unfollow-buttons works FIRST time - always, but never on second try. Other things that are depending on javascript still works so it's not an error in js either.

```
//html snippet
<div id="start-members">
<div class="content">
    <div class="result">
        <div class="items-column member"><div class="image-holder">
        <img src="imagefile"></div>
        <span class="button-section">
        <a href="#" data-userid="61" class="follow button trans-effect follow-user"><span class="following-text">Follow</span><span class="unfollow-text">Unfollow</span></a>
        </span>
        <div class="clearfix"></div></div>

        <div class="items-column member"><div class="image-holder">
        <img src="imagefile"></div>
        <span class="button-section">
        <a href="#" data-userid="95" class="follow button trans-effect follow-user"><span class="following-text">Follow</span><span class="unfollow-text">Unfollow</span></a>
        </span>
        <div class="clearfix"></div></div>

        <div class="items-column member"><div class="image-holder">
        <img src="imagefile"></div>
        <span class="button-section">
        <a href="#" data-userid="104" class="follow button trans-effect follow-user"><span class="following-text">Follow</span><span class="unfollow-text">Unfollow</span></a>
        </span>
        <div class="clearfix"></div></div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>

//jQuery
//This returns html and put it into result-div above
function getLatestMembers() {
    var getLatest = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/index.php/members/getlatest',
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    //If success, returning html
    getLatest.done(function(data) {
        $("#start-members .result").html(data);                
    });                        

    getLatest.fail(function(ts) {
        alert(ts.responseText);
    });            
}

//Toggle between following this user or not
$(".content .button-section").on('click', '.button.follow-user', function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
    //doing toggle of the button (to unfollow-user/follow-user)
    getLatestMembers(); //When having this call it renders the div latest members and next time this event is not fired. why?
});

//Unfollow user that has created this outfit
$(".content .button-section").on('click', '.button.unfollow-user', function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
    //doing toggle of the button (to unfollow-user/follow-user)
    getLatestMembers(); //When having this call it renders the div latest members and next time this event is not fired. why?
});
```

I've also tried just having `getLatestMembers()` in the event call. Next time the event is not fired.

```
//Unfollow user that has created this outfit - fired only once
$(".content .button-section").on('click', '.button.unfollow-user', function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
    getLatestMembers();
});
```

I hope I've described the scenario so you guys understand my problem/issue:-) (Question is: Why is not event fired more then once?)

Comment: you are replacing the button in getLatestMembers()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: can you put those event binding sections of the code into a separate function, and call that function every time within the getLatest.done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you update the section, you destroy the elements you've hooked the event on, and don't hook the events on the new elements that replaced them.

This code:

```
$(".content .button-section").on('click', function() { /*...*/});
```

finds elements that exist *at that moment in time* and hooks up a handler to them. But then this code:

```
$("#start-members .result").html(data);
```

destroys those elements and replaces them with new ones.

Use event delegation instead:

```
$("#start-members").on("click", ".content .button-section", function() { /*...*/});
```

That hooks the `click` event on the `#start-members` element, but tells jQuery to only trigger your handler if the event travels through elements matching the selector we give as the second argument. Since you don't destroy and recreate `#start-members`, the handler stays in place.

Comment: i actually figured something similar out just after posting my question. But I used $(".content").on('click', '.button-section .button.unfollow-user', function(e) { - because .content isn't destroyed. Thanks for answer! :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld: Sure, that'll work too, provided `.content` elements aren't created/destroyed dynamically. So would `.result` (with the same proviso). I picked `#start-members` because I wasn't sure there wouldn't be multiple `.content` or `.result` elements being created/removed dynamically (while I figured an element with an `id` probably wasn't). :-)

Comment: :-) I just posted an answer to my own question, but I will of course accept your answer soon (when I'm allowed to)

Answer (score 0):

Haha. Just because I posted this question I figured it out. In case some one else has similar issues...

**I changed:**

```
$(".content .button-section").on('click', '.button.unfollow-user', function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
    //doing toggle of the button (to unfollow-user/follow-user)
    getLatestMembers(); //When having this call it renders the div latest members and next time this event is not fired. why?
});
```

**TO**

```
$(".content").on('click', '.button-section .button.unfollow-user', function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
    //doing toggle of the button (to unfollow-user/follow-user)
    getLatestMembers(); //fired each time now
});
```